# What does it mean to call something "Naive" in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, definition

I've seen the term "naive" come up repeatedly in mathematics textbooks and lectures without any knowledge of what it indicates.

There is always the dictionary definition, but my impression of the word based on how I've seen it used is that it's similar to "trivial," where it has connotations in mathematics that differ significantly from those in natural language, even if it doesn't have a formal definition as such.

Can anyone who's spent more time immersed in the jargon of mathematics give me an impression of what naive means in this context?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory)

Comment: It's pretty much always "obvious" or "natural."

Comment: I would say that “naive” refers to what is usually the easiest approach, the one that takes the least effort to attempt, or the one that doesn’t take into account the potential intricacies that are revealed by a more careful study of the question.

Comment: I don't agree with the proposed synonyms.  Rather,  I think it means  something like "trusting that technical considerations don't get in the way".  Thus "naive arguments" need not be technically correct, as details are neglected.    Indeed, naive arguments may lead to false conclusions.

Comment: Naïve is used when one lets one’s intuition become more important than their rigour - applying theorems where the theorem is not defined or assuming the “obvious” when the reality is more subtle, etc.

Comment: It should also be emphasized that "naive" in the quasi-technical sense @lulu describes is generally _not_ a pejorative term. It carries an undertone of "it's entirely reasonable to _attempt_ to do things this way at first, hoping that the technicalities will work out eventually, and it takes a nontrivial amount of thought to discover that they actually don't".

Comment: To support @Troposphere's point, note that a very well-loved book by the great Paul Halmos is called *Naive Set Theory*.

Answer (score 5):

Among other uses, there are two quite specific uses that have become almost formalized themselves: "naive set theory" and "naive category theory". For naive set theory, it means *not* axiomatized, and not worrying too much about potential paradoxes (such as "the set of all sets that do not contain themselves as elements"), but focusing more on the positive possibilities. Similarly, beginning several decades later, "naive category theory" (a less universal convention) again avoids too much concern for foundations, either from set theory (Grothendieck universes, large cardinals, ...?!?), or more innately category-theoretic, as from Lawvere et al.

There is also a related-but-different "naivete", of physicists' computations that mathematicians could only genuinely justify after Schwartz and Grothendieck, using distributions and function-valued and operator-valued functions, etc. In these cases, in the happy outcomes, the computations could eventually be justified (and had matched physical facts all along!), but required much-more-sophisticated viewpoints to achieve the justification, or even to understand what might go wrong... but doesn't :)

Comment: (+1) ... but beware that "Naive Set Theory" is _also_ the title of an influential textbook by Paul Halmos, which does _not_ present the kind of "naive set theory" this answer describes.

Comment: @Troposphere, ha! Indeed! Tho' I'd claim that the Halmos book hijacks the sense of the phrase. :)  And, yes, certainly, there are _degrees_ of formalization of the language, of the meta-language, etc.

Comment: How an earth could Halmos have "hijacked" this term? Do you have relevant references for the use of the term before the publication of his book?

Comment: @RobArthan, my main point is that the popularity of his book "took over" the sense of the phrase. Indeed, I do not offhand know of prior use! And, as well, in my abstract algebra book (also on-line) I use that phrase somewhat similarly to Halmos' use, since I wanted to make an accurate reference. But certainly this usage is "less naive" than Cantor's, and less than many sources prior to the 1950s. Specifically, few parts of mathematics had felt a need to specify first-order logic, etc., as a language, nor explicitly specifying any meta-language at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Perhaps we can agree to say that Halmos "commandeered" or "pioneered" the use of the word "naive" in "naive set theory" and leave it there. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan, ... :)