Is it possible to invoke the empty function?
The empty function $f: \emptyset \rightarrow X$ is a function from the empty set to an arbitrary set $X$. Since $\emptyset$ is the only subset of $\emptyset \times X = \emptyset$, $f$ must be equal to $\emptyset$. Is it possible to invoke the empty function?
To clarify what I mean, consider a function $g: \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \{ 100 \}$ which is defined as $g(0) = 100$. Note that I am allowed to write $g(0)$ to obtain an image of $0$, which is $100$. What is not clear for me is whether it is possible to use the same notation for the empty function; even if you were to invoke one as $f()$, how do you know which element of the co-domain $X$ you obtain?

I'd argue that this not different from the definition of a variable. How do you know what $g(0)$ is? You need a definition for that. So define a function $f$ so that $f()=5$ but that of course is not different than being a variable $f:=5$. I'm not too versed in math, so I'm not sure if this actually qualifies as a function or just a map (I suspect it's not a function, just a map).

@infinitezero maps and functions are used synonymously, and what you said is not a function, nor a relation. You’re just specifying one element in the target space. OP: here the image is again the empty set, so you don’t get any element of the codomain.

Mathematics generally avoids this issue by having no concept of "invoking" a function. For any $x$ and $y$, $f(x) = y$ would be false if $f$ is the empty function.

It is meaningless to "invoke" a function without applying the function to some element of the domain.  If the domain contains no elements (because the domain is the empty set) then there is no element to which one can apply the function, so the function cannot be "invoked".  The notation f() has no meaning in the usual (mathematical) sense of a function f.

Am I right that If $f(x)$ has no meaning for the empty function, then every statement that involves this notation for the empty function is ill-defined?
For example, consider an injection test for the empty function: $\forall \alpha \forall \beta \in \emptyset(\alpha \neq \beta \rightarrow f(\alpha) \neq f(\beta))$.
Are we allowed to assume that the preceding logical statement is vacuously true when $f(x)$, under our supposition, has no meaning when applied to the empty function?

I wouldn't say that $f(x)$ has no meaning, just that $f(x)$ is undefined for all objects $x$. It's similar to how if $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $g(x):=x^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the value of $g((v_1,v_2))$ is undefined for every vector $(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, because $(v_1,v_2)$ is not in the codomain of $g$.

I think I would say $f(\alpha)$ only becomes undefined once you specify $\alpha$, even if there are no values $\alpha$ where it makes sense. Then your statement would be true. But I think this would be a matter of convention. I don't think there's a univeral agreement that $f(\alpha)$ doesn't become undefined until you specify $\alpha$. If this is relevant, you should explicitly say what you mean by it, or check what convention your teacher wants you to use.

The sequence of symbols "$f(x)$" does not have "no meaning"! It still means "the function $f$, when applied to some $x$ within the domain of $f$". It has meaning, just like "area of a four-sided triangle" has a meaning.

The pink dragon's favorite pair of shoes doesn't exist but is perfectly well defined. $f(x)$ is the same way. Putting a hat on an elf is not the same thing as dropping a hat on the ground, and saying "Well, since elfs don't exist dropping a hat an the ground is the same thing" doesn't make it the same thing.  In the same way, the notation of $f()$ is not the same thing as apply $f$ to an element of the empty set.... Or to put it another way, the concept of "nothing" is different than the concept of something that does not exist. The pink dragon and elves are no things but then are not nothing.

$f$ is a function iff for all $x$ in the domain there exists exactly one $y$ in the codomain such that $(x,y)\in f,$ and in that case we write $f(x)$ for the uniquely identified $y.$ Note the in that case: the notation $f(x)$ presupposes that $x$ belongs to the domain. For the empty function no $x$ can belong to the domain and therefore the notation $f(x)$ cannot acquire meaning.
The notation $f()$ would suggest a unary relationship; functions are by definition binary relationships.

Does it imply that the empty function has no concept of an image?

It does have an image set, but that set is the empty subset of the codomain. It does not have any images of individual points, by definition.

You can write $\forall x \in \emptyset,, f(x) = 7$, but you cannot write $\exists x \in \emptyset,,...$ and you cannot write $f(3)$ and you cannot write $f()$

You can certainly write something like $\exists x \in \emptyset, P(x)$ for any unary predicate $P$. It's just that this statement is always false.

Am I right that If $f(x)$ has no meaning for the empty function, then every statement that involves this notation for the empty function is ill-defined?
For example, consider an injection test for the empty function: $\forall \alpha \forall \beta \in \emptyset(\alpha \neq \beta \rightarrow f(\alpha) \neq f(\beta))$.
Are we allowed to assume that the preceding logical statement is vacuously true when $f(x)$, under our supposition, has no meaning when applied to the empty function?

@VladMikheenko Any proposition of the form ∀∈∅, P is vacuously true (even when P = ⊥). Like Stef said above, f(x) is indeed well-formed if x is quantified over the empty set. (Disclaimer: I'm speaking from the perspective of constructive logic, but I think this all holds in classical logic as well.)

The question is not whether a predicate can be formed over an element of the empty set (which it can, as several commenters have pointed out); the question is whether functional argument notation can be formed for a function with an empty domain. There the answer is no; it's a special case of the general constraint that functional argument notation cannot be formed with an argument that is not in the domain of the function, as in division by $0.$

@Lieven: The answer is yes, see my answer below.

Please clarify. Suppose we have function $f: X \to Y$. If $a\notin X$ and $b \in Y$ do you consider $f(a)=b$ to be false or indeterminate?

I kindly accept this answer after concluding that I can use $f(x)$ notation when it has no specific $x$.

When $f : X \to Y$ is an arbitrary function, you can invoke it on any given $x \in X$ - the rule is the same no matter what $X$ and $Y$ are. However, when $X$ happens to be the empty set, there is simply no $x \in X$ on which you could invoke the function. So theoretically invoking the function is possible, only there is no valid input to invoke it on.
Just as with any function, you can also compute the image of any subset $A \subseteq X$. With $X = \varnothing$ there actually is one such subset, namely the empty set. Therefore it makes perfect sense to write $f[\varnothing]$, and the result is - what else? - the empty set.

It seems perfectly legitimate to consider the empty function.  It is a binary relation that happens to be empty.  You can compose it with another function and get another empty function.  You can even square it, and obtain itself.  If $X$ and $Y$ are different spaces, the functions $\varnothing\to X$ and $\varnothing\to Y$ would apparently be the same entity from the set-theoretic viewpoint.


Is it possible to invoke the empty function?

In calculus, the concept of "invoking" a function (as in imperative programming languages, or something like the lambda calculus from Computer Science) does not exist. Since the formalization of calculus via set theory, $f$ is identified with a set; specifically, a binary relation. We can define many functions by a calculation (i.e. $f(x)=x^2$), but that is just an intuitive/naive definition (which is more than good enough in very many cases). Under the hood, it's sets all the way down.

What is not clear for me is whether it is possible to use the same notation for the empty function; even if you were to invoke one as (), how do you know which element of the co-domain  you obtain?

If you wish to use the function, you would never write it as $f()$, but as either $f$ (to talk about the function as a whole) or $f(x)$ (to talk about which value $f$ maps the variable $x$ to). $x$ here is akin to the variable name you would use in the "head" of a function definition in a programming language. Even if you know that there can never be a legal value supplied when calling your programming-language-function, syntactically you would still have to write it down. The same is true for the function syntax in maths.
$f(x)$ is well-defined for all $x\in\emptyset$, and undefined for all $x\not\in\emptyset$. Talking about $x\in\emptyset$ is perfectly fine in the context of logic statements like $\forall x \in \emptyset ...$  or $\exists x\in\emptyset ...$.
Check out the formal definition of functions on Wikipedia. In each of the three steps, every set is empty (i.e., the domain $X=\emptyset$, therefore the relation $\emptyset=R \subset X\times Y=\emptyset$), all $\forall$'s are automatically "true" and all $\exists$'s automatically "false" (by definition/axiom).

Per definition, a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a subset of $ A\times B$, which happens to verify the following condition: if (a,b) and (a,b') belongs to f, then b = b'.
With that in mind and the fact that $\varnothing \times B = \varnothing$, it is easy to follow that your empty function is nothing else that the empty set.

With this I mean that it is so legitimate to "invoque" the empty function as it is to do it with the empty set.

Let us skip the "is a function a triple, or its graph" debate and assume that the team defending "a function is its graph" has won.
For all sets $x, y, f$, let us denote $image(f,x,y)$ the sentence: $(x,y) \in f$.
A set $f$ is called a function if for all $z \in f$, $\exists x,y,\ z = (x,y)$ and if $\forall x,y,y',\ (image(f,x,y) \wedge image(f,x,y')) \Rightarrow y = y'$.
It is an easy exercise to check that the empty set is a function.
Moreover, $f(x)$ is an abbreviation. That is, every time you write a statement $P$ with $f(x)$ appearing somewhere, what you are really writing is actually the statement $\forall y, image(f,x,y) \Rightarrow P[f(x) \to y]$, where $P[f(x) \to y]$ means "every time you see $f(x)$ in the definition of $P$, replace it by $y$", assuming $y$ does not appear anywhere in $P$ (if it does, choose another letter that does not appear in $P$).
Using this rule, you can write $f(x)$ in every formula you like, even if $f$ is the empty function, and even if $f$ isn't a function at all, and any $x$. For example, let $f$ be the empty function, and let $x$ by any set. Let us prove the following sentence: $\forall z,\quad f(x) \neq z$. Indeed, by the rewriting rule I just gave, this sentence is equivalent to $\forall y,\ \forall z, \ image(f,x,y) \Rightarrow y \neq z$. To prove this, let $y$ and $z$ be sets. Then $(x,y) \not \in f$, since $f = \emptyset$. Therefore, we have the negation of $image(f,x,y)$. From this, we can deduce $y \neq z$, so the assertion is proved.
So, writing $f(x)$ is completely harmless, from a strictly logical point of view. The only thing is that for $f$ that are not functions, or for $f$ that are functions and when $x$ is a set not in their domain, you can prove anything from the assumption $\exists y, f(x) = y$.
The word "invoke" has no meaning in mathematics.


Is it possible to invoke the empty function?

Yes. Using the commonly used definition of a function, ordinary set theory, and a form of natural deduction, we can formally prove the existence of function $f$ such that $\forall a: [a\in \emptyset \implies f(a)\in X]$ (60 lines, available on request). Hint: The graph set is $g=\emptyset \times X$.

Even if you were to invoke one as $f()$, how do you know which element of the co-domain $X$  you obtain?

In this case, $f(x)$ is indeterminate/undefined for every $x$ since that $x$ will not be an element of the domain of $f$.

Can you please show how you formally proved it? I am interested in the process itself. Or at least point me ina  direction because right now I am lost.

As requested: https://www.dcproof.com/EmptyFunctionArbCodomain.htm

Every function $f$ satisfies the condition, not just the empty function. Anyway, what do formals proofs or set theory have to do with the question at all? It's a simple question for which the naive set theory is more than enough.

@Adayah A formal proof eliminates the need for any "hand-waving" arguments about simply extending the usual notions of functions to empty sets. To many readers including the OP, it may not be so "intuitively obvious" .

If that is your motivation, you should be formally proving that it is impossible to invoke the empty function (which you can't do anyway, because it is not a valid mathematical theorem). Meanwhile you suggest formally proving the existence of $f$ such that $(\forall a) \big( a \in \emptyset \implies f(a) \in X \big)$ (which is inaccurate and not what the OP asked), then you proceed to "hand-wave" the answer to the actual question.

@Adayah The OP asked, "Is it possible to invoke the empty function?" Now, "invoke" is not a mathematical term, but I took it to mean "formally construct" or "prove from set theory axioms the existence of" the empty function, which I did. I made use of Cartesian products to construct a graph set $g = \emptyset \times X$ . I used a formal definition of functionality to infer the existence of the required function $f$. See link.


"invoke" doesn't mean "prove existence". Invoking a function means applying it to some argument. Thus clearly the OP's question can not be formalized and formal proofs are of no use. 2. In axiomatic set theory the empty function is the empty set, so the formal proof of its existence consists of literally just invoking the empty set axiom. 3. What you wrote is not a mathematical formal proof. It might be a formal proof in some weird proprietary language of yours unrelated to mathematical logic. 4. The conclusion of your proof has nothing to do with the existence of the empty function.


Even just writing $\emptyset \times X$ instead of just $\emptyset$, as if it were not obvious that these two are equal, hints that you have little idea about how proving things from the axioms works in mathematics.

@Adayah Re: Applying a function to some argument. I wrote: "In this case, $f(x)$ is indeterminate/undefined for every $x$ since that $x$ will not be an element of the domain of $f$." The domain being $\emptyset$.

@Adayah Re: "The empty function is the empty set." You seem to be confusing the graph of the function $g=\emptyset \times X$ (an empty set of ordered pairs) with the function $f$ defined as $\forall a, b:[ a\in \emptyset \land b \in X \implies [f(a)=b <=> (a,b)\in g]]$. Your approach does not distinguish between $f(a)=b$ being false or being indeterminate.

Set theory does not distinguish between a function and its graph. A function is literally a set $f$ of ordered pairs satisfying the property $$(\forall x, y, z) \big( (x, y) \in f \wedge (x, z) \in f \implies y = z \big).$$ Respectfully, grab a textbook on set theory because you seem to be unfamiliar with the very basics.

@Adayah Apparently it also does not distinguish f(a)=b being false or being indeterminate. No wonder mathematicians have had improvise to some extent when it comes to Set Theory. Terence Tao, for example, in his popular textbook, "Real Analysis I," he defines a function as follows...

"3.3.1 (Functions). Let X, Y be sets, and let P(x, y) be a property pertaining to an object x ∈ X and an object y ∈ Y , such that for every x ∈ X, there is exactly one y ∈ Y for which P(x, y) is true (this is sometimes known as the vertical line test). Then we define the function f : X → Y defined by P on the domain X and range Y to be the object which, given any input x ∈ X, assigns an output f(x) ∈ Y ,defined to be the unique object f(x) for which P(x, f(x)) is true. Thus, for any x ∈ X and y ∈ Y ,y = f(x) <=> P(x, y) is true." The predicate P serves as a kind of graph for the function f.

Terrence Tao is known for being unconventional in the ways of presenting mathematics to newcomers. This style comes from the assumption that being too rigorous and formal makes it harder for the beginner to understand the underlying concept. And bless him for that, I hope his approach achieves what it is designed for. However, I am pretty much convinced Tao would never offer this kind of definition to actual mathematicians. It's just too cumbersome and silly.

@Adayah I'm guessing most mathematicians would agree that it is important to distinguish  f(a)=b being false from it being indeterminate.

@Adayah I don't see anything less rigorous about Tao's approach here. On the contrary, it seems to me that most formal definitions in mathematics restrict the domain to which they apply, i.e. a definition will not be applicable for anything not in its domain. If anything, saying that a function is just a set of ordered n-tuples may even represent a "dumbing down" of the concept.

You are right in that distinguishing between $f(a) = b$ being false and being indeterminate, as well as all sorts of "restricting the domain", are useful in ordinary (naive) mathematics. But in the axiomatic set theory - the theory that the current discussion is about, and where you aspire for your "formal proofs" to belong - it would only introduce unnecessary complications. Thus, as I said initially: for the purposes of formal proofs, the empty function is equal to the empty set and that's really all she wrote.

@Adayah There is nothing "naive" about it. It has all been quite formalized. (See my proof.) If you want to avoid "unnecessary complications," take a few shortcuts, etc., you may well want to... simplify matters, as you suggest here.

"Naive mathematics" is a coined term, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218546 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory .

@Adayah From your Wikipedia link: "Naive set theory is any of several theories of sets used in the discussion of the foundations of mathematics. Unlike axiomatic set theories, which are defined using formal logic, naive set theory is defined informally, in natural language." The system I use in the above proof is based on formal logic and axioms of set theory. So, by this definition, it is not naive.
